# unable to detect the file type of an uploaded pdf in php

Tags: php, pdf, file-upload

I have a multi file uploader that seems to be working only every now and again.  I've uploaded many pdf's to the system but every now and again it seems to not detect the file type of the document.

I have a document entitled
45278 Combined Report.pdf

Its not locked nor does it have any security,  it opens fine on my machine. However when I run it through the uploader it fails and says unsupported file extension. Here is a small portion of my code that runs the upload

```
 public function uploadMultiFile($idcompany, $createdBy, $filePath)
 {
   foreach ($_FILES['file'] as $k => $l) 
   {
     foreach ($l as $i => $v) 
     {
        if (!array_key_exists($i, $files)) $files[$i] = array();
        $files[$i][$k] = $v;
     }
   }  

   print_r($files[$i]);
 }
```

From this point i use https://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm to actually upload the document.

The array result as displayed......

```
Array
(
   [name] =&gt; 45278 Combined Report.pdf
   [type] =&gt; 
   [tmp_name] =&gt; 
   [error] =&gt; 1
   [size] =&gt; 0
)
```

Comment: `error => 1` indicates an error. And `size => 0` too.

Comment: @u_mulder thank you for your reply :)  yes error 1 is file to big.  The document is 3.5Mb. my phpini files says this....     upload_max_filesize 400M
post_max_size 400M
max_input_time 600
max_execution_time 600